# How to make this wordpress proxy work

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to make this request to be submitted to our backend front the frontend.

The frontend part looks like this:

```
  jQuery.ajax({
                url: IC.ajaxurl, //http://localhost/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
                type: "GET",
                data: {
                    action: "get_search_suggestions",
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("data", data);
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    console.log("ERROR", err);
                }
            });
```

I'm not a wordpress dev so I tried copying what the WP dev has done for the proxy and this is what I got, but still not working:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_get_search_suggestions', function() {
    $api = new ArangoConnector();
    $data = stripslashes($_POST["data"]);
    send_json_response($api->getSuggestions($data));
});
```

The getSuggestions() methods:

```
public function getSuggestions($data)
{
    $data = ($data);
    $json = json_decode($data);
    if (!$this->role_helper->isUserAllowedtoView($json->id))
        self::generateErrorResponse(self::PERMISSION_ERROR);

    $url = $this->getBaseUrl() . self::SEARCH_SUGGESTIONS . "/{$json->id}/";
    $response = wp_remote_get($url, self::getDefaultArgs());

    return self::generateResponse($response);
}
```

NOw when I trigger this call from the frontend I get this error in the networks panel of google chrome:

[image]

Comment: please share IC.ajaxurl code

Comment: Request URL: [...]wp-admin[...] : It looks like that you are trying to do an admin action while it is either not an admin action or you are not logged in

Comment: @ShitalMarakana thanks its `http://localhost/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`

Comment: remove  url: IC.ajaxurl
try this url: <?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>